# Building out a well-structured service layer

Tags: application-design, code-structure

First, I want to say that it has been awhile since I've gotten into the kind of detail I am at currently.  Lately, I've been very much in the SharePoint world and my entire thought process was focused there for quite some time.  I'm very glad to be creating databases again, writing "lower level" code to deal with data access, and so forth.

I'm working on a very simple web application and taking the opportunity to reacquaint myself with the way I used to structure my projects and various layers of code.  For instance, I might have created something like this the last time I went about building something basic from scratch:

```
- MyProject/
 -- Domain/
  --- Impl/
   ---- Person
 -- Model/
  --- IPersonRepository
  --- Impl/
   ---- PersonRepository : IPersonRepository
 -- Services
  --- IPersonService
  --- Impl/
   ---- PersonService : IPersonService
```

That would have been the project I did the real work in, and then referenced in the ASP.NET project.  My approach was very much inspired by what I saw from the CodeCampServer project as at that time ASP.NET MVC was still very new and it was the only open project I could find actively being developed, and by solid people at that.

What ways are you going about structuring your projects and code, when it comes to a general problem you're working on?  Certainly various problems can put constraints on this, but assume it's a basic problem without specific needs that affect the structure and layout of your code.